# My Android App keep crashing because of failure to render Button widget in my Java class file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a form within my android app using an API with the help of retrofit to submit the form to an online server. But my app keep crashing after clicking the submit button with the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.namtaxsenumerator, PID: 13907
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.namtaxsenumerator.MainActivity.createRequest(MainActivity.java:196)
        at com.example.namtaxsenumerator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7156)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7129)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27543)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

This is my MainActivity class

```
package com.example.enumerator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.util.Calendar;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputEditText FullName;
    TextInputEditText StickerNumber;
    TextInputEditText Address;
    TextInputEditText Email;
    TextInputEditText Phone;
    TextInputEditText Nationality;
    Spinner State;
    TextInputEditText LGA;
    TextInputEditText RC;
    TextInputEditText DriversLicenseNo;
    TextInputEditText LicenseIssued;
    TextInputEditText LicenseExpiry;
    Spinner VehicleType;
    TextInputEditText VehicleLicense;
    TextInputEditText VehicleTyres;
    TextInputEditText LGAofOperation;
    TextInputEditText NOKFullName;
    TextInputEditText NOKAddress;
    TextInputEditText NOKPhone;
    TextInputEditText NOKEmail;
    TextInputEditText NOKNationality;
    Spinner NOKState;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    Button reset;
    Button submit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextInputEditText FullName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.FullName);
        TextInputEditText StickerNumber = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.StickerNumber);
        TextInputEditText Address = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        TextInputEditText Email = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        TextInputEditText Phone = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
        TextInputEditText Nationality = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Nationality);
        Spinner State = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.State);
        TextInputEditText LGA = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LGA);
        TextInputEditText RC = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.RC);
        TextInputEditText DriversLicenseNo = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.DriversLicenseNo);
        TextInputEditText LicenseIssued = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LicenseIssued);
        TextInputEditText LicenseExpiry = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LicenseExpiry);
        Spinner VehicleType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.VehicleType);
        TextInputEditText VehicleLicense = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.VehicleLicense);
        TextInputEditText VehicleTyres = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.VehicleTyres);
        TextInputEditText LGAofOperation = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LGAofOperation);
        TextInputEditText NOKFullName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKFullName);
        TextInputEditText NOKAddress = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKAddress);
        TextInputEditText NOKPhone = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKPhone);
        TextInputEditText NOKEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKEmail);
        TextInputEditText NOKNationality = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKNationality);
        Spinner NOKState = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.NOKState);

        //Submit Button
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveUser(createRequest());
            }
        });


    public UserRequest createRequest(){
        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
        userRequest.setStickerNumber(StickerNumber.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setFullName(FullName.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setAddress(Address.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setEmail(Email.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setPhone(Phone.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNationality(Nationality.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setState(State.getSelectedItem().toString());
        userRequest.setLGA(LGA.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setRC(RC.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setDriversLicenseNo(DriversLicenseNo.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setLicenseIssued(LicenseIssued.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setLicenseExpiry(LicenseExpiry.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setVehicleType(VehicleType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        userRequest.setVehicleLicense(VehicleLicense.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setVehicleTyres(VehicleTyres.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setLGAofOperation(LGAofOperation.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKFullName(NOKFullName.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKAddress(NOKAddress.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKPhone(NOKPhone.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKEmail(NOKEmail.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKNationality(NOKNationality.getText().toString());
        userRequest.setNOKState(NOKState.getSelectedItem().toString());

        return userRequest;
    }

    public void saveUser(UserRequest userRequest){
        Call<UserResponse> userResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().saveUser(userRequest);
        userResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Successfull!" +t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know where I have gone wrong in my code as I have checked and researched all night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not initializing the variables but creating new ones on onCreate() whose scope is inside onCreate().

Hence, the variables you declared outside onCreate() are always null and you get the exception.

Make these changes in your onCreate() method code and it will work fine

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FullName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.FullName);
    StickerNumber = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.StickerNumber);
    Address = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Address);
    Email = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
    Phone = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
    Nationality = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.Nationality);
    State = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.State);
    LGA = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LGA);
    RC = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.RC);
    DriversLicenseNo = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.DriversLicenseNo);
    LicenseIssued = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LicenseIssued);
    LicenseExpiry = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LicenseExpiry);
    VehicleType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.VehicleType);
    VehicleLicense = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.VehicleLicense);
    VehicleTyres = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.VehicleTyres);
    LGAofOperation = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.LGAofOperation);
    NOKFullName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKFullName);
    NOKAddress = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKAddress);
    NOKPhone = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKPhone);
    NOKEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKEmail);
    NOKNationality = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.NOKNationality);
    NOKState = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.NOKState);

    //Submit Button
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveUser(createRequest());
        }
    });
}
```